# Java Print - Ending Escape Sequences

Tags: java, escaping, println

In Java the escape sequence `"\033[0;1m"` can be appended onto the beginning of strings in order to bold the text in compatible terminals and consoles. The problems is that this does not just bold the one line, it bolds all subsequent lines in the terminal as well. Is there an escape sequence or character that can be appended to the end of the string in order to close off the escape sequence?

```
System.out.println("\033[0;1m" + "This is bold.");

System.out.println("This is also bold."); // Goal is to make this not bold.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested but I believe you need to change the font back to normal using another escape sequence.

```
System.out.println("\033[0m" + "This is also bold");
```

Comment: This worked!                                                      `System.out.println("\033[0;1m" + "This is bold." + "\033[0m");`

`System.out.println("This is no longer bold.");` Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help!